# Programatically creating a XLS with a drop down cell in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am currently creating XLS files programatically using Python and the `XLWT/XLRD` libraries.

I've been able to fill the cells with values and insert simple formulas. My challenge is that I want to create a drop down for my users (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-remove-a-drop-down-list-HP005202215.aspx)

Yes, I can easily do this in EXCEL, but I need to have this process automated - I'm using Python and the `XLWT/XLRD` libraries - I'd rather stick with them, but I'll switch to something else if necessary (I'm in a Ubuntu Linux Server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can not - unsupported by XLWT/XLRD.

Comment: Do you know a library that would support it? I can't use .NEt, but anything Python, Perl, PHP, or Ruby is valid game.

Comment: A `.xlsx` file is just a bunch of `.xml` files zipped together, it is not that hard to generate. Rename a `.xlsx` file to `.zip` and see for yourself.

Comment: Good idea Paulo - but I have to read the Spreadsheet back in, and XLRD does NOT read XLSX :(

Comment: openpyxl can read and write xlsx: http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/ . I don't know if it supports making dropdown though.

Comment: Nothing in Python seems to do what I need - gonna use Perl, it seems to have a more mature XLS plugin.

Comment: @andreas how did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 8):

openpyxl also supports drop down cell in XLSX files via data validation: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, [xlsxwriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter/0.4.3) can handle drop down lists on XLSX:

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_data_validate.html

Answer (score 0):

```
worksheet = workbook['SheetName']
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1=formula, allow_blank=False, showDropDown=False)
worksheet.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add(worksheet["D7"]) # cell in worksheet where drop-down will be added
```

important:
set `showDropDown=False` in `DataValidation` function
formula1 - must have str type with "" added so the following formatting can be used: `formula = '"' + formula + '"'`

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is going through the COM.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html

From there, you have all the options available to you in Office's native Visual Basic -- including (at the very least) the ability to send clicks and keypresses to various objects in the window.

Comment: COM needs windows, I'm using Linux